# how to load videos from firebase database using urls in recycler view

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to know that how to load multiple videos in `RecyclerView` using url from firebase database in my application please help me and also give suggestions for which video library should I use

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting **absolute path like "http://videocdn.bodybuilding.com/video/mp4/62000/62792m.mp4"** of file like this you can use default videoview widgets to your recyclerview layout items rest thing is to make ui for play and pause for videoview

check this link [videoview in recyclerview](http://berlinchan2017.blogspot.com/)

i think there's no need to use library for this even though if you are looking for libray [google's exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) is better choice

Comment: yes it is right but in this i want to use firebase database to load multiple videos in recyclerview like youtube and at all i did not want to give any specific url for a video i want to load multiple videos from firebase